# Compute rotation angle of fits image

Tags: python, astropy, fits-header

I have a fits image and the header has the keys PC1_1, PC1_2, PC2_1, PC2_2. I want to compute the angle by which my image is rotated so that North will be up. I use the formula below:

angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(PC1_2, PC1_1)) .

The answer I get is 156.0 deg however when I load the image on DS9 I get the following direction.

[image]

Does this mean that the angle is measure from the negative x-axis and so I should use angle_true = 180 - angle or am I using a wrong formula?

Comment: It depends on how you count and orient your pixel coordinate system. Often its origin is in the top left.